# How to create DataFrame where some fields changes and remaining repeats?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is sample output:

```
S_URL   NAME    PHONE   PRODUCT PRICE
link1   Name1   Phone1  prod1   price1
link1   Name1   Phone1  prod2   price2
link1   Name1   Phone1  prod3   price3
link1   Name1   Phone1  prod4   price4
link2   Name2   Phone2  prod1   price1
link2   Name2   Phone2  prod2   price2
link2   Name2   Phone2  prod3   price3
link2   Name2   Phone2  prod4   price4
```

Basically each seller have multiple products.

I tried

```
dictn = {"seller_link":"link1","name":'Name1',"phone":"Phone1","Product":["prod1","prod2","prod3","prod4"],"Price":["price1","price2","price3","price4"]}
dictm ={"seller_link":"link2","name":'Name2',"phone":"Phone2","Product":["prod1","prod2","prod3","prod4"],"Price":["price1","price2","price3","price4"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(dictn)
df2  =pd.DataFrame(dictm) 
df = pd.concat([df2,df])
print(df)
```

but it gives output like:

```
s_link  name    phone   Product Price
link2   Name2   Phone2  prod1   price1
link2   Name2   Phone2  prod2   price2
link2   Name2   Phone2  prod3   price3
link2   Name2   Phone2  prod4   price4
link2   Name2   Phone2  prod1   price1
link2   Name2   Phone2  prod2   price2
link2   Name2   Phone2  prod3   price3
link2   Name2   Phone2  prod4   price4
```

I don't understand where is the link1 then?

Comment: Could you provide more information? What is the input? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Arkadiusz updated please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the fields in a column are the same you can do something like this

```
import pandas as pd

df_data = pd.DataFrame({
  "S_URL": "link1",
  "NAME": "Name1",
  "PHONE": "Phone1",
  "Product": ["prod1", "prod2", "prod3", "prod4"]
})
```

As an option you could create a dataframe per distinct set of S_URL, and then concat them using `pd.concat([df_1, df_2, ...])`.

But I feel like it would be just easier to generated the dataset using python list comprehensions and then use it for pandas.

**UPDATE**

I concatenated the dataframes from your questions, I aslo used next code and it output exactly what you asked:

```
df = pd.concat([df2, df], sort=False)
print(df)

  seller_link   name   phone Product   Price
0       link2  Name2  Phone2   prod1  price1
1       link2  Name2  Phone2   prod2  price2
2       link2  Name2  Phone2   prod3  price3
3       link2  Name2  Phone2   prod4  price4
0       link1  Name1  Phone1   prod1  price1
1       link1  Name1  Phone1   prod2  price2
2       link1  Name1  Phone1   prod3  price3
3       link1  Name1  Phone1   prod4  price4
```

Comment: @Ashawin Your code seems to work fine, I just tested it. I only added a small change.
I also can tell you that I'm using pandas > 1.0.0

Comment: Ahh.. thanks it was a pandas version error. I was on 1.0.4 now upgraded to 1.2.0 and it got fixed.